# How to fix Models aren 't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-models

in django 1.8

models.py

```
class hotel(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sell(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey("hotel")
    sell_text = models.CharField(vmax_length=20)

class Selled(models.Model):
    buy_choices = [(data.id, data.sell_text) for data in Sell.objects.filter(Hotel_id=2)]
    city = models.IntegerField(choices=city_choices, default=1)
```

command ./manage.py runserver

```
   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

why i can't use `Hotel_id` for filter

takeout the `Hotel_id` Will be running

Comment: Did you try `schemamigration`?

Comment: same error message appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do a database query before django has managed to set up the database, so django tells you that the "Models aren't loaded yet".

It looks as though you want to give a model field dynamic choices with a query, which you cannot do a load time. What's more, it looks like you need a `ForeignKey`, not an `IntegerField`.

You should look at [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

```
class Selled(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('Sell', limit_choices_to={'id': 2})
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you can run your application in the development server you must connect your project to an existing database (or create one onfly with SQLite).

After settings are correct to use a DB you must run the following command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This will create necessary tables inside your DB to start working. You can check all necessary information in relation with DBs here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/

Comment: I have existing database，takeout Hotel_id Will be running

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't understand correctly your question